# Extract of audio duration using Tika

Tags: java, apache-tika

How can I view the audio **duration**'s metadata of a .FLAC audio file?

I am using tika-parser in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
    <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
    <version>1.24</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is my code:

```
public void test(String path){
    InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
    Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
    ContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
    ParseContext context = new ParseContext();
    parser.parse(input, handler, metadata, context);
    System.out.println(metadata);
}
```

**Attached the screenshot of the .flac file details** the .flac details have the length, I am not so sure if the metadata retrieved from the code is related to the details over here.

[image: attached]

**Attached the screnshot of the metadata values from the intellji debug mode**, xmpDM:duration is in the key-value of the metadata

[image]

Comment: Is it a FLAC-in-Ogg file or a native FLAC one?

Comment: Generally `xmpDM:duration` will hold it if available - https://tika.apache.org/2.5.0/api/org/apache/tika/metadata/XMPDM.html#DURATION

Comment: @Gagravarr, I have attached some screenshot in the post.. The xmpDM:duration isn't inside the metadata.. is there anywhere can I retrieve the duration?

Comment: The FLAC parser doesn't currently calculate the length - https://github.com/Gagravarr/VorbisJava/blob/master/tika/src/main/java/org/gagravarr/tika/FlacParser.java#L81 - do you fancy helping? Would need something to calculate the length then share it, similar to https://github.com/Gagravarr/VorbisJava/blob/master/tika/src/main/java/org/gagravarr/tika/OggAudioParser.java#L115

Comment: I have found the solution yesterday. Tested with a few .FLAC audio file and it works fine. I will be posting the solution, I am not sure if this is a correct solution, please comment. thank you

Answer (score 1):

This solution works for me and I have tested with a few .FLAC file.

```
private static double getFLACDuration(String path) throws Exception {
   InputStream in = new FileInputStream(path);
   InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(in);
   FlacFile flac = FlacFile.open(input);
   return (double)flac.getInfo().getNumberOfSamples()/flac.getInfo().getSampleRate();
}
```

Comment: Based on https://gist.github.com/lukasklein/8c474782ed66c7115e10904fecbed86a that looks to be correct for files where the total number of samples was written to the header, but beware that it may not always be set by the encoder based on the comments in that file...

Comment: I see. thank you for the info. I checked the org.gagravarr.flac.FlacInfo class, I think the numberOfSamples variable is calculated in the code. I guess, it should be fine? Please advise, if any. thank you

Comment: If the encoder wrote the number of samples into the info block, that code will provide it. If the encoder didn't (maybe due to streaming?) then you'll just get back 0